# How to read a value back from the memory location in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, unsafe

I am writing a simple C# code, wherein I am making use of Pointer to read a value from the memory location.
The code works fine when I try to read the value from the same method where I insert the value. However, it does not work when I try to access the value outside of the method.

Here is my code block:

```
    class Program
    {
        public unsafe static int* numberPointer;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InsertValueIntoMemoryAddress();
            ReadValueFromMemoryAddress();
        }
        public unsafe static void InsertValueIntoMemoryAddress()
        {
            int number = 100;
            numberPointer = &number;
            Console.WriteLine("The value of Number is {0}", *numberPointer);
            Console.WriteLine("The address of Number is {0}", (int)numberPointer);

            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr((int)numberPointer);
            int value = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
            Console.WriteLine("Inside the same method --- The value from a Memory location {0}", value);
        }
        public unsafe static void ReadValueFromMemoryAddress()
        {
            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr((int)numberPointer);
            int value = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
            Console.WriteLine("Outside from the method -- The value from a Memory location {0}", value);
        }
    }
```

Here is the output of the above program:

**The value of Number is 100**

**The address of Number is 10416820**

**Inside the same method --- The value from a Memory location 100**

**Outside from the method -- The value from a Memory location 10416820**

Can someone help me why it is not able to read the value from the memory address outside of the method; instead, it just returns the memory address?

Comment: Note: .net is managed. Addresses are normally not guaranteed to be static over time. Its able to rearrange itself. Although, that might not be the case here. Still a question remains; why use pointers in .net?

Comment: You would have to [fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement) the variable - Do you have a good reason to do that in the 1st place??

Comment: Did you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Due to this:

```
numberPointer = &number;
```

The `number` memory space is on the stack and will be freed after exiting the scope of the method.